# Has any Catholic scholar fully explained the deeper meaning of the allegory of eagle in Deut 32: 11-12?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, deuteronomy

We read in Deut 32:11-12 (NRSVCE):

> As an eagle stirs up its nest,
> and hovers over its young;
> as it spreads its wings, takes them up,
> and bears them aloft on its pinions,
> the Lord alone guided him;
> no foreign god was with him.

The allegory of the eagle and how it rears its young, gives a picturesque presentation, on how the Lord cares for his people. I have heard it said that a particular kind of eagle which builds its nest on mountain-cliffs, does the base-work with thorny bushes, over which a soft layer of feathers is laid. When the chicks hatch, they have a smooth bed to sit on; but when they grow up and refuse to leave the comfort of the nest, the parent eagle stirs up the nest so that the thorny base is exposed which makes it impossible for the the chicks to stay put. There is more to the way the eagle trains its young to fly high.

My question is: **Has any Catholic scholar fully explained the deeper meaning of the allegory of eagle in Deut 32: 11-12?**

Comment: Is it actually a full blown detailed allegory with deeper layers of meaning, or a simple and intuitive metaphor that's able to be understood by almost anyone?

Comment: Thanks, Sean OConnor.  The allegory may be simple enough for  the rural population. As for those urban people who may not be regularly watching the National Geographic,  a little bit of explanation on how the eagle forces its lazy chicks out of the nest , would be great value. The famous sermon of American Baptist Minister Rev. CL Franklin beautifully presents Deut 32: 11-12 . The text is available on the net.  I wish to know if any Catholic scholar has contributed  with a similar write-up.